# Xamarin.Forms Get Click on Collection view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I have set up this collectionview:

```
       <CollectionView  
            SelectionMode="Single"
            Grid.Column="1"
              x:Name="listview_allAds" 
              BackgroundColor="#00000000" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  >
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
                <!--Span is number of items in one row-->
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView Padding="5,5,5,5"> <!--only way to set padding-->
                        
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="#00000000">

                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" 
                                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <BoxView BackgroundColor="#424242"
                                     HeightRequest="150"
                                     WidthRequest="80"/>

                                <Label 
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                    Text="{Binding adresse}"
                                    FontSize="15"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    FontFamily="Font_11"
                                    TextColor="Gray"
                                    />

                                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label 
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                        Text="{Binding title}"
                                        FontSize="20"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                                        FontFamily="Font_11"
                                        TextColor="#424242"
                                         />

                                    <Label 
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                        Text="{Binding price}"
                                        FontSize="15"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        VerticalOptions="End"
                                        FontFamily="Font_11"
                                        TextColor="#424242"
                                         />

                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>

                    </ContentView>



                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

This looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to simply get the click on an item. I tried with OnCollectionChanged like so:

```
    private void listview_allAds_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string current = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as AdType)?.title;
    }
```

But this behaved wierd. On first click, it did give me the correct item I clicked on. But if I click on the same item again, it is simply not fired. If I click on another item afterwards, the function fires again, giving the right result. If I click on the same item again, again not firing.

Also I noted that when I click on an item only the first and third item get this "click" animation on the item. None of the other items produce this click animation?

1. How do I handle the clicks correctly?
2. Why is this animation exclusive to item 1 and 3 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take care that you use the SelectionChanged event and not an "OnTap" event.
So, if you tap on the same item again the selection isn't changed, so no event is fired. If you want to customize the tap behavior I think you should think about to use a GestureRecognizer or in particular a TapGestureRecognizer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap

also referenced in this thread:

[Xamarin Forms CollectionView TapGestureRecognizer not firing on label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914705/xamarin-forms-collectionview-tapgesturerecognizer-not-firing-on-label)

Comment: It is correct what you say. I was hoping for this component to be more flexible. anyway I ended up using flowlistview component. It does this way better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private void listview_allAds_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string current = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as AdType)?.title;
     listview_allAds.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

With
listview_allAds.SelectedItem = null;
means you can click it again because nothing is selected again

Comment: This does work, but now NO animation is triggered AND the event handler is fired multiple times...